# Prismic Query - Query by Category

Tags: nuxt.js, prismic.io

I have this product structure:

[image]

And I would like to query by the `uid` of **toys**. However, this query is not working:

```
const products = await this.$prismic.api.query([
  this.$prismic.predicates.at('my.product.category','toys'
)]
```

It doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Fairly new to Prismic so this took me a while to figure out. The method is very straightforward:

Once you make a relationship between two types (ie, products and categories), you can use this query to get products by a specific category:

```
const products = await this.$prismic.api.query(
   this.$prismic.predicates.at('my.product.category', 'category_id')
)
```

The category id is found in the category document (it looks something like: `X_uidsfsdFKHF2`). Per the documentation, that is the ONLY way to make this query work. You can't use `uid` or `type`.

[image]